# Group boolean operators for bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to perform the following test in bash:

```sh
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" || >&2 echo "Could not change working directory to pipeline repository root" && exit
```

When the `cd` works properly, the script exits. However, I only want it to exit when the command fails.

So essentially I want something like this:

```sh
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" || (>&2 echo "Could not change working directory to pipeline repository root" && exit)
```

But the `(...)` is not valid syntax for grouping boolean operators. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `{...}` to group without subshell creation.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure what you mean when you say `(...)` is "not valid syntax". It's syntactically valid, it just has side effects that defeat the `exit` (specifically, it creates a subshell and executes the code therein inside that subprocess, so `exit` exits the subprocess rather than the parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" || {
  rc=$?
  >&2 echo "Could not change working directory to pipeline repository root"
  exit "$rc"
}
```

- Use `{ }` instead of `( )` to do grouping without subshell creation.
- We need to store `$?` before the `echo` so the `exit` reflects `cd`'s exit status, and not `echo`'s. (This bug was present in your original code).

Comment: Community-wiki to avoid gaining rep from answering a known duplicate.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. The error message does not print out and the script does not exit.

Comment: Well it actually looks like it is an issue with my `cd ...` command. It returns a 0 status code even if the `git` command fails. How do I get `cd` to fail if the `git` command fails?

Comment: I'd split it into multiple commands. `dir=$(git rev-parse ...) || die "Could not determine repository root"; cd "$dir" || die "Could not change directory to repository root"` -- assuming you have `die() { rc=$?; (( $# )) && echo "$*" >&2; exit "$rc"; }`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the `(( $# ))` in that `die` function?

Comment: @wheeler, so we don't print an empty line if given no arguments.